# Merge two SELECT queries with different WHERE clauses

Tags: sql-server

I have one table of services. I need to merge two SELECT queries. Both have different where clauses. For example

```
SELECT 
  U_REGN as 'Region', 
  COUNT(callID) as 'OpenServices',
  SUM(CASE WHEN descrption LIKE '%DFC%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 'DFC'
FROM OSCL
WHERE     
  ([status] = - 3) 
GROUP BY 
  U_REGN
ORDER BY 
  'OpenServices' desc
```

This gives me result

```
Region    | OpenServices | DFC
Karaci    | 14           | 4
Lahore    | 13           | 3
Islamabad | 10           | 4
```

I have another query

```
SELECT 
  U_REGN as 'Region', 
  COUNT(callID) as 'ClosedYesterday'
FROM OSCL
WHERE 
  DATEDIFF(day, closeDate, GETDATE()) = 1
GROUP BY 
  U_REGN
ORDER BY 
  'ClosedYesterday' desc
```

It gives me result

```
Region    | ClosedServices
Karachi   | 8
Lahore    | 7
Islamabad | 4
```

I need to merge both results, and show ClosedServices beside the DFC column.

Comment: There's an inconsistency - your second query produces a column called ClosedYesterday but the example data says ClosedServices.

Comment: What does "merge" mean?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Treat your two current queries' resultsets as tables and join them:

```
select
    FirstSet.Region,
    FirstSet.OpenServices,
    FirstSet.DFC,
    SecondSet.ClosedYesterday
from 
(
    SELECT U_REGN as 'Region', COUNT(callID) as 'OpenServices',
    SUM(CASE WHEN descrption LIKE '%DFC%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 'DFC'
    FROM OSCL 
    WHERE ([status] = - 3) 
    GROUP BY U_REGN 
    --ORDER BY 'OpenServices' desc
) as FirstSet
inner join
(
    SELECT U_REGN as 'Region', 
    COUNT(callID) as 'ClosedYesterday'
    FROM OSCL
    WHERE DATEDIFF(day, closeDate, GETDATE()) = 1
    GROUP BY U_REGN
    --ORDER BY 'ClosedYesterday' desc
) as SecondSet
on FirstSet.Region = SecondSet.Region
order by FirstSet.Region
```

Not the prettiest bit of SQL I've ever written but hopefully you'll see how it works and understand how to maintain it.

I suspect a better-performing query would be a single `SELECT` from OSCL, grouped by U_REGN, with each of your three counters as separate `SUM(CASE ...)` statements akin to what you do currently for DFC.  This will be a single table scan, at most, depending you your indexes & schema.

Comment: What happens when there's results in one subquery that aren't there in the other? I'd suspect you actually want a full outer join here.

Comment: @Simon - fair point, but that wasn't the OP's given scenario.

Comment: Thank You, this is what I wanted, Thanks! And also Thanks @SimonRigharts . Inner join wasnt showing me all results I intended, so I Used full outer join, works perfectly :)

Answer (score 7):

Building off Michael's suggestion:

```
SELECT
    U_REGN AS 'Region',
    SUM(CASE WHEN [status] = -3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'OpenServices',
    SUM(CASE WHEN [status] = -3 AND [description] LIKE '%DFC%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'DFC',
    SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(day, closeDate, GETDATE()) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'ClosedYesterday'
FROM
    OSCL
GROUP BY 
    U_REGN
ORDER BY
    'OpenServices' desc
```

Comment: Thank You Simon, but I used @Michael Green's query with full outer join because this query gives me even those regions which doesnt have any open or any closed service!